# How to use Lazy enumeration to control processes?

Tags: ruby, process, lazy-evaluation

In his talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZjwEPupybw Pat Shaughnessy says that it's possible to use Lazy enumeration to control processes that you are not sure when they should end.

I'm curious is it real or this is just some theoretical possibility of doing this?

If you know any real world example or open source project please drop me link. If you have your own explanation/implementation please share it with me. I'm just curious, nothing more :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pat's blogged at length about the lazy enumerator. You may well have found this already but in case not: http://patshaughnessy.net/2013/4/3/ruby-2-0-works-hard-so-you-can-be-lazy

Appreciate it's not a real world example but is certainly a very thorough intro and explanation.